# How to handle both parent/child relationship and attributes

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I'm building a database of html tags and attributes.
The ul tag has an li tag as a parent/child relationship.
The li tag has a 'value' attribute, so it's not really a parent/child relationship. 'value' is an attribute, not a tag.

How would you set up a table structure to handle parent/child relationships as well as attributes?

```
create table tag
(tagid int identity primary key
,tagName varchar(max)
)
go
create table prop
(propid int identity primary key
,parentid int
,childid int
)
go
```

I could add another field to the 'prop' table to determine if this is truely a parent/child relationship or an attribute relationship:

```
alter table prop
add typeid int
```

But am I starting down the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is three tables: Tag, TagProperty, and TagToTagProperty.

1. Table Tag holds the Html tag name with a self pointing reference to the parent tag.
2. TagProperty holds the Html tag properties
3. TagToTagProperty table is a linking table between the Tag and TagProperty where a tag can only have one distinct property per tag: PRIMARY KEY (TagId, TagPropertyId)

Try the code bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE Tag (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(126),
ParentTagId INT NULL
)

GO

CREATE TABLE TagProperty
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(126)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TagToTagProperty](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TagPropertyId] [int] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_TagToTagProperty_TagId_TagPropertyId PRIMARY KEY (TagId, TagPropertyId)
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT INTO TAG (Name, ParentTagId)
VALUES('UL', NULL); --UL tag has no parent therefore ParentId is Null

INSERT INTO TAG (Name, ParentTagId)
VALUES('LI', 1); -- LI tag has a parent therefore parentId is one
INSERT INTO TagProperty (Name)
VALUES ('value')

go
/*
    Linking table between tag and attributes
*/
INSERT INTO TagToTagProperty( TagId, TagPropertyId)
VALUES 
(1,1),
(1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ErnestoDeLaRuiz! Q: How do I know that "value" is an attribute, but li is a child?

Comment: The LI record above has a ParentTagId equals to 1. This means that if you look in the same table in the Id field for the number 1, you will find its parent. On the other hand, the TagProperty table only holds properties, and 'value' is a property shared by more than one tag. So you need a linking table. TagToTagProperty links the Tag Id with the TagPropertyId.

Comment: Oh I see. You've added on field for the parent/child relationship and another for the tag/attribute relationship. OK. Thanks!